# Nodejs with MYSQL problem to query outside the connection method

Tags: mysql, node.js

I make a function that connect once to mysql server and it work fine.
now i make other function to just query but i cant do this.
i call this function in my app.js

import:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const config = require("../configuration/config");

const connectToDB = () => {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(config.database);
  connection.connect(err => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
  console.log("MYSQL DB CONNECTED");
};
```

then i make this function

```
const getAllUserReports = userID => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reports = mysql.query(
      `SELECT reports.id,report_types.[type],companies.id as companyID,reports.[year]
      FROM reports
      INNER JOIN report_types on reports.reportTypeID=report_types.id
      INNER JOIN companies on reports.companyID=companies.id
      where reports.creatorUserID=${userID} and active_report=1
      `
    );
    resolve(reports);
    reject("Server Error");
  });
};
```

i call the second function in my routes but "mysql.query" not work.
in sql server its work like this.

There is other way to make it ?? I dont want to connect after once query i want one connect when server on.

Comment: Try with this  `connection.query( ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [mysql npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql),  you can't run a query from the `mysql` object. You must run it from the `connection` object instead. You must say

```
const reports = connection.query(/*whatever*/, function(error, results, fields) {
    /*handle query results*/
})
```

or the promisified equivalent.  Otherwise the mysql package has no idea which connection to use.

And, with respect, your tactic of opening the connection just once and reusing it is **doomed to failure** if your server keeps running for any amount of time; if the connection drops your server can't proceed.

Use a [connection pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections). Then grab a connection from the pool for every query you must run. That puts connection management onto a robust and debugged piece of code.
And, you'll get concurrent asynchronous querying as well.

Something like this (which I have not debugged) might work.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const config = require("../configuration/config");
const pool mysql.createPool(config.databaseConnectionPool);

...

let resultset;
pool.query (/*whatever*/, function (error, result, fields) {
   if (error) throw error;
   resultset = results;
});
```